# hook_node_insert() doesn't work

Tags: hooks, 8

hook_node_insert() doesn't work after node insertion in Drupal 8. When I'm trying to get the node details in that hook, it's not working.

My code is the following one.

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function test_node_insert(EntityInterface $node) {
    dpm($node);
}
```

Comment: Notice that you are merely stating facts, without asking any explicit question. "Doesn't work" is also quite broad, and it doesn't tell users what exactly is wrong. Are you saying you checked the hook is invoked, and it doesn't seem it is? Are you getting a different result than what you are expecting?

Comment: As this answer is still the top result in Google - if you just added the node_insert call to an existing module and the hook seems not working, try clear drupal cache :)

Answer (score 4):

How about hook_entity_insert

```
function hook_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity){
  // do something
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8

Comment: Drupal 8 still invokes `hook_node_insert()`. Do you have any reason to think `hook_node_insert()` would not work, but `hook_entity_insert()` would?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use hook_node_presave(). This function work with new node and update node (hook_node_insert run for new node). And better you can use class **Drupal\node\NodeInterface;**

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for node entities.
 */
function node_test_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
  kint($node);
}
```